# #1054 Error in updating mysql

Tags: mysql

I am getting this response

```
1054 - Unknown column 'with_login' in 'savsoft_quiz'
```

when trying to execute

```
ALTER TABLE `savsoft_quiz` ADD `quiz_template` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Default' AFTER `with_login` ;
```

How can I correct it?

[image]

Comment: Give some additional information, for example, the database related tables

Comment: I think the message is pretty clear

Comment: does your table `savsoft_quiz` have already column `with_login`, check syntax.

Comment: it works perfectly fine if with_login column is already there in your table

Please paste result of `desc savsoft_quiz `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to add a new field after a field called with_login, which doesn't exist.

You have a couple of options:

1. remove "AFTER `with_login`" from the end of the SQL statement and try running it again. This will add the field to the end of the table. If that's not what you want:
2. change "AFTER `with_login`" to name one of the fields that exists in the table. The new field will be added after the field you specify.